# Unable to import package of one bundle from another in OSGI

Tags: java, osgi, osgi-bundle, blueprint-osgi

I have a multi module maven project in eclipse. I tried exporting package from one module/Bundle, so it could be accessed in another module.
But I am not able to access package/classes of one bundle in another.

My porject Structure is as follow:

```
MainProject  
    Module1  
        subModuleA  
        subModuleB  
        subModuleC  
    Module2  
    Module3
```

I import a package from Module3 and want to use it in subModuleC, but   when I type the package name, it is not accessible.
I am using Apache ServiceMix and Apache Karaf to write and deploy my Bundles.
Part of POM.xml can be seen below:
(Also what BundleType should I choose for my Bundles???)

Configuration of Module3:

```
        <configuration>
            <instructions>
                <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                <Bundle-Description>${project.description}</Bundle-Description>
                <Import-Package>*;resolution:=optional</Import-Package>                      
                <Export-Package>org.MyProj.ManageSQL.Interface.*, org.postgresql.*, com.mysql.jdbc.*</Export-Package> 
                <Private-Package>org.MyProj.ManageSQL.*, org.json</Private-Package>
                <BundleType>??</BundleType>
            </instructions>
        </configuration>
```

Configuration of subModuleC:

```
        <configuration>
            <instructions>
                <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                <Bundle-Description>${plantcockpit.os.description}</Bundle-Description>
                <Import-Package>
                    org.apache.camel.osgi,
                    org.MyProj.ManageSQL.Interface.SqlService,
                    com.fasterxml.jackson.core,
                    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.*,
                    com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jsonSchema.*,
                    org.apache.commons.net.ftp.*,
                    *           
                </Import-Package>
                <Export-Package>
                    org.MyProj.SubModuleC
                </Export-Package>
                <Private-Package>
                    org.MyProj.SubModuleC.*,
                    org.json,
                </Private-Package>
                <Bundle-Type>???</Bundle-Type>
            </instructions>
        </configuration>
```

Comment: You probably don't need those `Import-Package` blocks at all. Delete them. Especially the one attached to Module3... why would you want to make ALL imports of a bundle optional?? Regarding `Bundle-Type`, there is no such OSGi header so you can delete that too. Or put whatever you like there, I guess.

Comment: The `Private-Package` sections are also pointless.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you exporting `org.postgresql` package? Just install the official jar if you need the package. Embedding it and exporting it  may lead to some weird dependency chains or classloading issues. Same for `org.json`.
Common libraries should live in their own bundles. If you want/need to embed them in your bundle you must [know what you are doing](https://www.manning.com/books/osgi-in-action).

I suggest that you leave the job of resolving imports and exports to `maven-bundle-plugin`. When your bundles work then tweak by hand.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <instructions>
            <Import-Package>
                *
            </Import-Package>
            <Export-Package>
                !this.package.will.not.be.exported,
                *
            </Export-Package>
        </instructions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

There are some tools to inspect bundles import/export at runtime. From [Karaf console](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KARAF/4.1.+Console+and+Commands#id-4.1.ConsoleandCommands-OSGishell) type `headers <bundleid>` or `imports <bundleid>`. Karaf will show you what packages are imported and from what bundle.

Comment: `<Import-Package>*</ImportPackage>` is redundant, as that's the default.